# SSIS Pipeline performance counters

Tags: performance, logging, ssis

I am trying to log the performance counters for my SSIS Pipeline, for things like Buffer memory, Buffers in use, Buffers spooled, etc.

I created a new log and added all those counters to it. Things are beeing logged, at every 15 seconds to the file, but all it's beeing logged are values of 0 - no matter the time of execution or the element beeing counted.

Something is wrong, but I don't know what... and google-ing it, I could find just a couple of people having this problem also, but no actual solution to it.

Any ideea is apreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you applied all the latest service packs?